# UDPClient in separate thread Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, udpclient

Earlier this week I was able to get a Delphi UDPClient to work (with help).  Now I need to run the client procedure in a separate unit and in its own thread.  Is there a simple example or at least pseudo code someone can share?  I was to avoid using TForm in the thread because I will get the returned data from the thread and display into TMemo field.  I am having specific issue with completely defining my Type IdUPDClient..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TTask to run some code in a separated thread, add to uses System.Threading.

```
TTask.run(procedure
    var UDPClient : TIdUDPClient;
  begin
    UDPClient := TIdUDPClient.Create(self);
    UDPClient.Host := 'put your host';
    UDPClient.Port := 0;//PUT YOUR PORT
    UDPClient.ReceiveTimeout := 5000;
    UDPClient.BufferSize := 8192;
    UDPClient.Active := True;
    while True do //put your condition here
    begin
      //some code
      //When you need to update the screen you should syncronize
      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure
      begin
        form1.Memo1.Text := 'update';
      end);
    end;
    UDPClient.DisposeOf;
  end);
```

Comment: thanks.   If I want the value returned to display in a TMemo, how do I access Task.run returns.  I know technically procedures do not return values,  but can I still capture output.  I know in C or even Perl I can.

Comment: Just update what you need inside of `TThread.Synchronize`, you can update a memo inside a form `form1.memo.text := 'update'` or call  a procedure on a datamodule `datamodule1.update()`, etc...